# Sum of values of indexes stored in a sequence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this model:

$V = \{1, 2, 3, 5\}$

$V_n = $ value of n-indexed element of set V

$W = \{0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1\}$

$W_n = $ value of n-indexed element of set W

$X = $ any sequence of elements from set $V$, ex: $X = (1, 2, 2, 5)$

$X_n = $ value of n-indexed element of sequence X

Now, what I want to do is to properly describe that my parameter $S_X$ will return sum of $W's$ under same index as $V's$ stored in $X$.

I can't put it any clearer sadly, so I'll try to explain it with this pseudocode:

```
V = {1, 2, 3, 5}
W = {0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1}
X = (1, 2, 2, 5)

sum = 0

for n = 0, n < count(X), n=n+1 do
  i = V.indexOf(X[n])
  val = W[i]

  sum += val
end
```

How can I describe that code as a $\sum$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^{len(w)}w_i$

$\sum_{i=1}^{len(w)}w_i$

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't seem right. I would assume that X and V would be in this equation aswell.

Comment: The indexes are the same.

Comment: Yeah, but I would assume this will sum up 0.01 + 0.02 + 0.05 + 0.1 (1,2,3,5) rather than 0.01 + 0.02 + 0.02 + 0.1 (1,2,2,5)

Comment: w is a sequence of elements from W.  w$_i$ is the i-th element of the sequence.

Comment: I modified my approach.

Could you tell me if this makes sense?

I've changed X not to hold values of V, but rather to hold indexes - since $|W| = |V|$.

My way of summing $W$ by indexes is done like this: $$\sum_{n=0}^{|X|}W_{X(n)}$$ Also worth mentioning that I've also described $X_n$ as n-th element of sequence X.

Comment: Looks acceptable, @JCode

Comment: Thanks for your input.